# Should accept the data if the image field is empty using php

Tags: php, mysql

I am writing the query to accept image  field only svg,png,jpeg format.But if the image field is empty it is displaying as error while uploading,actually it should insert  the remaining fields like name and all if  I am not adding image also.Here is my query.

example.php

```
$title=$_POST['blog_title'];
$result = str_replace(" ", "-", $title);
$description=$_POST['blog_description'];
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])){
$name=$_FILES["image"]["name"];
$type=$_FILES["image"]["type"];
$size=$_FILES["image"]["size"];
$temp=$_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"];
$error=$_FILES["image"]["error"];
$ext = strtolower(pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
if($error > 0){
    die("error while uploading");
}else{
    $permissible_extension = array("png", "jpg", "jpeg", "svg", "jpg","jpe");
    if(in_array($ext, $permissible_extension)){
        if(move_uploaded_file($temp,"upload/".$name)){
            $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO blogs(image,blog_title,blog_description)values('$name','$result','$description')");
            if($sql){
                header("Location:blogimage.php");  
                exit();
            }else{
                echo "Insertion failed";
            }
        }else{
            echo "File couldn't be uploaded";
        }
    }else{
        echo "Invalid format";
    }
}
}else{
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO blogs(blog_title,blog_description)values('$result','$description')");
if($sql){
    header("Location:blogimage.php");  
    exit();
}else{
    echo "Insertion failed";
}
}
```

Comment: "**it should upload the image if there is no image**" does it make sense to you ?

Comment: if iam not adding image and i submit the record then it should insert right what is there to make does it make sense to you?

Comment: Can you share with us the error that is displayed?

Comment: @david rosa Iam giving name,description and keeping image as empty and if i submit the data it is getting error while uplaoding.it should upload if i didnt select image also.

Comment: Yes, I know, we all already know that, my question is, what is the error that you are getting? Also, did you see the php logs?

Comment: it has been solved i have updated my code

Comment: If you check this you will see why you are getting an error http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, mandatory advice against the use of `mysql_*` functions. This is deprecated, use `mysqli_*` [functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Now, your issue. If you want to store the other informations about the file even when the filetype is empty or wrong, you will need to do your INSERT before the test.

Below are some code to you try:

```
<?php
//connect to the database using mysqli
$name=$_FILES["image"]["name"];
$type=$_FILES["image"]["type"];
$size=$_FILES["image"]["size"];
$temp=$_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"];
$error=$_FILES["image"]["error"];
if($error>0)
    die("error while uploading");
else
{
    //Insert the informations in your database here, so even without the upload, the info about the file will be stored
    $query = mysqli_query("INSERT INTO blogs(image)values('$name')");
    if($type == "image/png" || $type == "image/jpg"|| $type == "image/jpeg" || $type == "image/svg" || $type == "image/jpe" || $type==" ")
    {
        move_uploaded_file($temp,"upload/".$name);
        echo "upload complete"; 
    }
    else
    {   
        die("Format not allowed or file size too big!");
    }
}
```

Comment: No it is not working in my db iam having three columns name,image and description,if i will not select image and gives only name and description then it is geting as error while uploading.

Comment: Please can anyone help me regarding this if the image field is empty also it should insert the data into database of remaining columns.